# Updating same html Element with jQuery when user input changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying do some calculations that take user input and supply the calculated value for the user to see. The user will supply two values and then the result, ADF, will be returned.

Two problems that I am having: The value is calculated before I have entered the second value (FG); and when either value is changed, the old ADF is not replaced. I understand that is because it keeps applying .append(), but I do not know what I need to use instead. I have provided pictures of what is happening. I have listed my code below.

*Note the round() and ADF() functions are my Javascript functions used for the calculations and I didn't think it relevant to list that code. Let me know if you think it is relevant to see it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
function main() {
  $(document).on('change', '#Gravities', function () {
    OG = $('input[name=OG]').val();
    FG = $('input[name=FG]').val();
    var calc = round(ADF(OG,FG)*100, 2); 
    $('.ADFbox').append('<div class="ADF">'+calc+'%</div>');
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<body>
   <form id="Gravities"> 
      <div>
         <p><label class="originalGravity">OG: <input type='text' name='OG' value =""></input></label></p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <p><label class="finalGravity">FG: <input type='text' name='FG' value=""></input></label></p>
      </div>
   </form>
   <div class = 'ADFbox'>
      <p>ADF:</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSV6c.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFkSQ.png)

Comment: let me know if my answer is what you're looking for, else I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("input", ".gravity", function() {
  var thisval = $(this).val()
  var nothisval = $(".gravity").not(this).val()

  if (thisval.length > 0 && nothisval.length > 0) {//check if one value is empty
    OG = $('input[name=OG]').val();
    FG = $('input[name=FG]').val();
    //var calc = round(ADF(OG, FG) * 100, 2);
    var calc = OG * FG;//change this computation
    //$('.ADFbox').append('<div class="ADF">' + calc + '%</div>');
    $('.ADFbox').text("ADF:" + calc).change();


  } else {
    $('.ADFbox').text("ADF: 0");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form id="Gravities">
    <div>
      <p><label class="originalGravity">OG: <input type='text' class="gravity"name='OG' value ="" /></label></p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p><label class="finalGravity">FG: <input type='text' class="gravity" name='FG' value=""/></label></p>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class='ADFbox'>
    <p>ADF:</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Check of each value then proceed if both value has length more than 0

Note: input has no ending tag just close like `<input />`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you could place the `.adf` div in the HTML on load and then simply update it's `text()` instead of using `append()` to create a new copy after each calculation.

Below is a working example. Note that I simplified the calculation as you didn't provide the logic of the `round()` or `ADF()` functions. Try this:

```js
function main() {
  $(document).on('change', '#Gravities', function() {
    OG = $('input[name=OG]').val();
    FG = $('input[name=FG]').val();
    //var calc = round(ADF(OG, FG) * 100, 2);
    var calc = OG * FG;
    $('.ADFbox .adf').text(calc + '%');
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="Gravities">
  <div>
    <p>
      <label class="originalGravity">
        OG: 
        <input type='text' name='OG' value="">
      </label>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>
      <label class="finalGravity">
        FG: 
        <input type='text' name='FG' value="">
      </label>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
<div class='ADFbox'>
  <p>ADF: <div class="adf"></div></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Me either, but it is what it is. I guess a working snippet isn't enough for some

Comment: Thank you for the help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are appending html not updating the existing text value.

Just change your code like below:

```
$(document).on('change', '#Gravities', function () {
    OG = $('input[name=OG]').val();
    FG = $('input[name=FG]').val();

   if(OG != "" && FG != ""){

     var calc = round(ADF(OG,FG)*100, 2); 
     $('.ADFbox').find("p").html("ADF:"+ calc + '%');

   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function main() {
  $(document).on('change', '#Gravities', function () {
    if($('input[name=OG]').val()!='' && $('input[name=FG]').val()!=''){
       var calc = round(ADF(OG,FG)*100, 2); 
       $('.ADFbox').html('<div class="ADF">'+calc+'%</div>');
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
 <body>
   <form id="Gravities"> 
     <div>
    <p><label class="originalGravity">OG: <input type='text' name='OG' value =""></input></label></p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <p><label class="finalGravity">FG: <input type='text' name='FG' value=""></input></label></p>
  </div>
      </form>
  <div class = 'ADFbox'>
    <p>ADF:</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `html('')` is redundant as your next call overwrites the `innerHTML` anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have added on change event. that's why it's getting calculated each time when any one of the fields got updated. I made few changes:

```
   <form id="Gravities">    
        <div>
          <p><label class="originalGravity">OG: <input type='number' name='OG' value =""></input></label></p>
        </div>

        <div>

 <p><label class="finalGravity">FG: <input type='number' name='FG'         value=""></input>
      </label></p>
        </div>
    <button type="button" id="fgs">
    Find ADF</button>
    </button>
      </form>
        <div class = 'ADFbox'>
          <p>ADF:</p>
        </div>

    function main() {
      $("#fgs").on('click', function () {
        OG = $('input[name=OG]').val();

        FG = $('input[name=FG]').val();

        var calc = OG*FG; 
        document.getElementsByClassName("ADFbox")[0].innerHTML= "ADF:"+" " +calc;
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(main);
```

created working fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/Safoora/hspdgqca/15/

Comment: Thank you for the help with this.

Comment: you are welcome. If the above answer was useful, upvote for that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm not understanding you. As per my understanding you need to calculate only if both inputs field are changed? If it is so, you can do like this:

```js
function main() {
  $(document).on('change', '#Gravities input', function () {
    OG = $('input[name=OG]');
    FG = $('input[name=FG]');
    $(this).data('changed',true); // set "changed=true" for current input
    // Check if both input fields are changed
    if(OG.data('changed') == true && FG.data('changed') == true){
      //var calc = round(ADF(OG.val(),FG.val())*100, 2); // uncomment this
      var calc = OG.val() * FG.val(); // comment this
      $('.ADFbox').html(function(){
        $('#Gravities input').data('changed',false); // set "changed=false" for next query
        return '<div class="ADF">'+calc+'%</div>'
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="Gravities"> 
      <div>
         <p><label class="originalGravity">OG: <input type='text' name='OG' value =""></input></label></p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <p><label class="finalGravity">FG: <input type='text' name='FG' value=""></input></label></p>
      </div>
   </form>
   <div class = 'ADFbox'>
      <p>ADF:</p>
   </div>
```